# How To Get Time Since Like 1972 in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I know in python that you can get the time in milliseconds since 1972 or some time around there. I wanted to know if there was a similar feature in Objective-C or if I need to make something to calculate it.

Comment: For reference `January 1, 1970` is called the epoch time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there's `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]`, which give the time (in seconds) since midnight on January 1, 1970.

`[NSDate date]` returns the current time; you can get the seconds-since-epoch relative to any time that you have an `NSDate` object for.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, you don’t care about the particular start date, just an elapsed-time number you can get milliseconds from. `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` will give you a double-precision value for the current system time.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be Objective-C:

```
long timeSinceEpoch = time(NULL);
```

Comment: `time(3)` returns `time_t`, not an `unsigned int`.